# Talking about feelings of a past event

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

I am confused about the use of tenses in describing an event in the past.

I went to a Funfair and I played several games.

(a) My favorite game is Ring toss. I like tossing the rings to the cones.

OR

(b) My favorite game was Ring toss. I like木 tossing the rings to the cones.

Which one is the correct one? Are both of them correct?

When I talk about the game rules, can I still use present tense?

(c)  For the Ring toss game, we need to draw an question card, then answer the question by tossing the ring to the corresponding cone.

(d) For the Ring toss game, we needed to draw an question card, then answered the question by tossing the ring to the corresponding cone.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Ring toss is still your favorite game (of all games you ever played), you say:

> My favorite game **is** Ring toss.

If Ring toss was your favorite game from the games available at that specific Funfair, but it is not your favorite game in general, you say:

> My favorite game **was** Ring toss.

If the same rules apply no matter where and when the game is played, you say:

> For the Ring toss game, we **need** to **draw** a question card, then **answer** the question by tossing the ring to the corresponding cone.

If the rules applied specifically to that game on Funfair (but can be different when played in other occasions), you say:

> For the Ring toss game, we **needed** to **draw** a question card, then **answer** the question by tossing the ring to the corresponding cone.

In the last case, *needed* is in the past tense, but *draw* and *answer* are in the indefinite (no tense) form "to draw" and "to answer." You do not see "to" before *answer,* because one "to" is enough for a series of verbs, for example: "We needed to draw, write, speak and dance."